# Retrieving the com class factory for component with clsid {00024500-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} For generating Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel

I am developing an application in ASP.NET  I am exporting data to excel file using some interop's dll's. earlier i have developed the application in Windows 2016 Server. at that time I could able to export the data to excel file. but recently when i have deployed my application on some other server on IIS I am getting this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005.

please let me know the resolution for this error

I have tried this solution. Still showing the same error:

In DCOMCNFG, right click on the My Computer and select properties.
Choose the COM Securities tab.
In Access Permissions, click Edit Defaults and add Network Service to it and give it Allow local access permission. Do the same for <Machine_name>\Users.
In Launch and Activation Permissions, click Edit Defaults and add Network Service to it and give it Local launch and Local Activation permission. Do the same for <Machine_name>\Users.

This are the steps i can come up with after little research in order to rectify my error.

Comment: Do you have Office installed on that new server?

Comment: Yes 2016 Version
 But i have other application on the same server where excel is working and been generated . i had the same issues with Word But with the help of the the Mentioned settings it started working . And made changes to the pool Version of IIS to Net 4.5v.
My Report Is generated on Pop-Up Page .